# Excel formula for easily inserting values for MySQL

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel

```
INSERT INTO phonebook VALUES('01', 'John', 'Doe', 'North America')
```

I have a table of records and it is A LOT. Inserting it one by one through phpMyadmin is a tedious job. 
I was thinking maybe there would be an excel formula for it where every word after commas are replaced. So I cant just copy the codes then run it on sql.

Comment: What format is the data in?

Comment: Its in .doc format. Its in a table. So I could paste it on excel so it'd be easier.

Comment: Copy to excel, then use string concatenation and cell references to create the INSERT stamements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your data in a CSV file or a plain text files. Assuming that fields/columns are separeted by TAB and lines/records sepeareted by NEWLINE. Save it on disk e.g. C:\phoneData.csv

Execute the following statement

> LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/phoneData.csv' INTO TABLE yourtablename

Remember that TAB and NEWLINE spearators are not neccessary to be used, you can use alternate terminators/spearators. See the following link for more details

[MySQL Load Data INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! Right now i cant test to see if it works since im on a pc with no xampp. But i made a csv file and it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/UBqumuR.png Will it work? Should I delete the column headers?

Comment: Yes it should work. For sake of ease copy the excel sheet and paste it in notepad and then save the file. (As it will do the tab and new line separation automatically in this way). 
You can delete the header or append "IGNORE 1 LINES" at the end of above stated LOAD statement.

Comment: So a .txt works too?

Comment: @jeffmangum I suppose the only difference between text and CSV is the file extension - at least for your case.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter what is the extension of file. The only thing that matters is the format of data inside that file.